# Intel Server Board S3420GP fails to boot with video connected

Tags: motherboard, post, xeon

Building a new system using an Intel Server Board S3420GP motherboard and an Intel Xeon X3440 processor. Before installing this motherboard into the chassis we want to test that it will actually boot correctly. We have mounted the processor and RAM with no hard drives attached.

The boot sequence differs between the next variable:
1) Connecting video results in the system fans ramp up and down, twice, and then the system beeps with the same behavior repeating; the system status light shows "Amber"
2) With no video, the system goes through POST and the diag LEDs show that the system is missing a bootable device

Need some assistance identifying why the board would fail to POST with video connected.

// Update //

Using another Power Supply the system gets passed the fans ramping up and down twice. Video still does not display.

Comment: I don't get the logic behind not mounting the board

Comment: Testing for faulty hardware before spending the time installing/mounting the hardware and then having to unmount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating with more information to assist others in the same predicament. The original problem as stated above was related to the configuration of memory and connecting a video display before connecting the power supply.

**Memory Configuration**
You should follow the [Memory Configuration Tool](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?ProductID=3146&DwnldID=17625&lang=eng&iid=dc_rss) found on the Intel Support website for this motherboard. It will save you a lot of trouble in the long run as we attempted to purchase RAM that matched the "Unbuffered/Registered", 1066/1333MHz requirements.

**Video Display** We experienced a unique beep sequence that reported "faulty power;" however, it was identified that the video display port was plugged into the board before power had been connected to the system. If we connected the power initially and then connect the video display port the server board would boot up correctly.

Hopefully this expanded solution provides adequate detail.

Comment: You can mark this post as the solution, you could also include more detail on that the specification discrepancy was. This will help others searching SuperUser for answers.